# Random time between two `LocalTime` (or `UTCTime`) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, time

I need to generate a random time between two given `LocalTime` values (but this can be `UTCTime` if necessary, as I can convert).

I achieve the generation of a number in the range `(0, n)` like this:

```
randomSeconds :: RandomGen g => g -> NominalDiffTime -> NominalDiffTime
randomSeconds rg max = realToFrac $ fst (randomR (0, max) rg)
```

and this is used like so:

```
randomTimeBetween :: RandomGen g => TimeZone -> LocalTime -> LocalTime -> g -> UTCTime
randomTimeBetween tz s e rg = addUTCTime (randomSeconds rg (diff tz s e)) (localTimeToUTC tz s)
```

where `diff` is

```
diff :: TimeZone -> LocalTime -> LocalTime -> NominalDiffTime
diff tz st en = diffUTCTime (localTimeToUTC tz st) (localTimeToUTC tz en)
```

However I'm in the endless cycle of compilation errors where it could not deduce `Random NominalDiffTime` or can't convert from `NominalDiffTime` because there's no instance for `(Fractional Int)` etc

What's the most appropriate/simplest/whatever way of me generating a random `NominalDiffTime` so I can then add that amount using `addUTCTime x utc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. For `randomSeconds` to work all you need to do is convert `NominalDiffTime` to seconds as an `Int` and since `NominalDiffTime` is an instance of `RealFrac` you can use `round`, `floor` etc. to do so. Also you don't want to discard your generator in helper functions, since you might need it later.

```
import           Data.Bifunctor (first)
import           Data.Time
import           System.Random

randomSeconds :: RandomGen g => g -> NominalDiffTime -> (NominalDiffTime, g)
randomSeconds rg max = first realToFrac $ randomR (0, truncate max :: Int) rg

diff :: TimeZone -> LocalTime -> LocalTime -> NominalDiffTime
diff tz st en = diffUTCTime (localTimeToUTC tz st) (localTimeToUTC tz en)

randomTimeBetween :: RandomGen g =>
  TimeZone -> LocalTime -> LocalTime -> g -> (LocalTime, g)
randomTimeBetween tz s e rg =
  first
    (utcToLocalTime tz . (`addUTCTime` (localTimeToUTC tz s)))
    (randomSeconds rg (diff tz s e))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  tz <- getCurrentTimeZone
  nowUTC <- getCurrentTime
  let yesterday = utcToLocalTime tz $ addUTCTime (-1 * 3600 * 24) nowUTC
      between =
        fst $ randomTimeBetween tz yesterday (utcToLocalTime tz nowUTC) gen
  putStrLn $ "Yesterday: " ++ show yesterday
  putStrLn $ "In between: " ++ show between
  putStrLn $ "Now: " ++ show (utcToLocalTime tz nowUTC)
```

Comment: `truncate` would be a safer choice; `floor` can give you an out of range value if `max` is a negative duration.

Comment: @jberryman, good point on out of range. Despite that negative `max` would be a bug in this program (you just don't start in the future and end in the past :) ), and I would take a different action on such an input, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the documentation there in an `Num` implementation for `NominalDiffTime` which offers the function `fromInteger :: Integer -> NominalDiffTime`.

Therefore: generate a `Integer` of the appropriate range, convert it to `NominalDiffTime` and add it to your time value.

Comment: `Integer -> NominalDiffTime` is only one part of the problem. I have a `NominalDiffTime` but I want to `randomR (0, max)` where `max` is a `NominalDiffTime`, *or*, e.g. an `Integer`. So how do I `NominalDiffTime -> Integer`? (Hoogle isn't much help here)